# Angularjs restful webservice call

Tags: angularjs

I want to develope one angularui like these. When I click submit button I want to cal one restful webservice developed by some one. Already my username and password is harded in restful webservice. when I request to restful webservice it will validate my username and password. If it is success it will display my data. If it is not success it will display login failed information.

case 1: In that html file I hard coded my username and password. In this case I'm able to send request to restful webservice and I am unable to get response from his machine

case 2:My question is my to bind my values to url. Here I'm sending my code. Can any one help me. How to bind my values to url and how to handle response.

username : one text box
Password : one text box
   submit button

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form  method="get" ng-submit="submit()">
<div ng-app="formmodule" ng-controller="submitController">
Name :<input type="text" ng-model="uname"></br>
pwd:<input type="password" ng-model="pwd"><br>
<br>


<button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</form>

<script>

var app=angular.module("formmodule",[]);


app.controller("submitController",function submit($scope,$http){
    var uname = $scope.uname;
    var pwd=  $scope.pwd;

     var url = 'http://9.000.000.000:2020/restDemo/rest/user/users?uname=abc&pwd=abc';
            $http.get(url).success(
                function(data)
            {

                         $scope.output = data;

            });



});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to pass values from your ng-model to your submit function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue i am seeing that your `ng-submit` is outside of `ng-app`, try placing the `ng-app` to the `<body>` or `<html>` tag:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="formmodule">
    <body>
       <form  method="get" ng-submit="submit()">
          <div ng-controller="submitController">
              Name :<input type="text" ng-model="uname"></br>
              pwd:<input type="password" ng-model="pwd"><br>
              <br>
              <button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
         </div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
      </form>
      .......
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai) has said about your ng-app being in the wrong place, you should make a couple edits to the HTML and JS. For the HTML you should do something like

```
<form  method="get" ng-submit="submit(uname, pwd)">
```

Here you just pass in the ng-models to your submit() function. From there, it's just inserting the values into your query string.

```
function submit(username, password) {
  var root = 'http://9.000.000.000:2020/restDemo/rest/user/users';
  var queryString = '?uname=' + username + '&pwd=' + password;
  var url = root + queryString;
  ...
}
```

When you assign your scoped variables to local variables in your controller

```
var uname = $scope.uname;
var pwd=  $scope.pwd;
```

you aren't really doing much as you can access the scoped variables anywhere in your controller. The above submit function could also be written:

```
function submit() {
  var root = 'http://9.000.000.000:2020/restDemo/rest/user/users';
  var queryString = '?uname=' + $scope.uname+ '&pwd=' + $scope.pwd;
  var url = root + queryString;
  ...
}
```

where you don't pass anything into your submit function.